# Why a "date" as "2021-07-20" (in mysql db) appear as "2021-07-19T22:00:00.000000Z" in laravel "echo"?

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-7, gmt

I had upgrade my laravel projet from v6 to v7 and now i had a problem with dates.

In mysql db i have a field of type "date" valued "2021-07-20" but when i do an "echo" in php i got "2021-07-19T22:00:00.000000Z".

Someone had an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line was the problem.

```
protected $dates = ['myDate'];
```

I had remove it to solve the problem